# Keycloak: Get authorization code in JSON?

Tags: openid-connect, x509, keycloak

we are working on a student project. Our goal is to achieve that a user can authorize with a x509 certificate via Keycloak.

Actually, we cannot continue with receiving the authorization code in order to exchange it for a token request. Basically, we send an authorization code request and receive the authorization code by an URL parameter. But we would prefer to receive the authorization code in a JSON format. The access type of the Client is set to public.

Can someone help us please.
Thank you.

Comment: The answer would be based on the following: do you want to authorize a user (operating an arbitrary Client) or a Client (= piece of software)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The authorization code flow is given in the url because it is meant to survive a redirection to the keycloak login page. You access the keycloak login page using a client id and a redirect url to your application. Once the login is successful, the keycloak server redirects to your app again, providing the authorization code appended in the url itself. Then your app sends this code in order to get a token set, which is the one actually given in JSON format.

It's not possible to get the authorization code from a REST endpoint, because it is meant to follow a web browser flow. You could still use the direct access grant in order to log in the users directly with their credentials and obtain the token set. That is however considered to be a bit weaker.

**See also:**

- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant

Comment: Is there any way i can access this token and save it somewhere ?

Comment: @JagadeeshKumarCK use the code retrieved from the redirection url to get the token from the auth rest endpoint. Then you can save it to local storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Can i ask one more doubt regarding the keycloak , Actually i have two public clients in Keycloak APP 1 and APP 2 , What i am trying to do it to get the token of APP 2 inside APP 1 , so when i login to APP 1,  i need to get the token of APP 2 as well , Can you give any help to solve this senario, I tried the token exchange but this is inside the client i can't use a confidential client @Artiz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083170/react-micro-frontent-authentication-using-keycloak