# Keycloak: Missing parameter: code, How to obtain the code in Keycloak using the POST request

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, keycloak, access-token

I am trying to make a `POST` request using the POSTMAN to my Keycloak but I keep getting the error `Code not valid`. I am not sure how to get CODE for the keycloak.

I have created the Realm, User, Client etc. when I make the request using the foolowing parameter then I get the success message with access token:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/blog_demo/protocol/openid-connect/token

grant_type: password
redirect_url: http://localhost:3000/callback
client_id: blog-post-demo-client-001
client_secret: 9a465bd2-1076-4c18-a12a-b53zd4f0908q
response_type: code
username: user1
password: password123
```

I put the access token in the `https://jwt.io/` to obtain some more info but I don't see the `code` anywhere.

Now I am trying to make the request using the following information:

```
 POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/blog_demo/protocol/openid-connect/token
    
    grant_type: authorization_code
    redirect_url: http://localhost:3000/callback
    client_id: blog-post-demo-client-001
    client_secret: 9a465bd2-1076-4c18-a12a-b53zd4f0908q
    response_type: code
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing parameter: code"
}
```

I know I have to send the `code` in my request but I am not sure what value should I send for it. Can someone please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: by code you mean, you want to get the `access_token` ?

Comment: I am also bit confused. We have to send the parameter `code` in the request for `grant_type: authorization_code`. Does code mean the access_token itself? Because normally we get the `access_token` as a response to the request right? But in my case it is asking for the `code` in the request itself. Hence I am getting the error `Missing parameter: code`

Comment: `grant_type: authorization_code` - means you need to use `Authorization Code Flow` - that requires browser. `code` is returned by authorization endpoint and then you exchange code for token with token endpoint. You can't do that easily with the Postman (that request to auth endpoint), because you need browser (or proper HTML parsing) - it's not an API call.

Answer (score -4):

Remove unnecessary parameters from your request. This should work :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/blog_demo/protocol/openid-connect/token

grant_type: password
client_id: blog-post-demo-client-001
client_secret: 9a465bd2-1076-4c18-a12a-b53zd4f0908q
username: user1
password: password123
```

Comment: Yes, this is working for me already. I want to use the `grant_type: authorization_code` and  get the access_token. But I am gettitng the errror: `Missing parameter: code`

Comment: What you are trying to achieve requires an `authorization code` which is to be passed in your request when you mention `grant_type: authorization_code`. Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311757/keycloak-get-authorization-code-in-json)