# React Micro Frontent Authentication using Keycloak

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have 3 standalone React Apps hosted on 3 different domains and its using Keycloak for authentication the tokens are saved in the localstorage and during a REST API call axios use the tokens from the localstorage and attach it with the header these are working fine as expected

- App 1 (Keycloak Client app_one)
- App 2 (Keycloak Client app_two)
- App 3 (Keycloak Client app_three)

All of the above clients are public clients

My goal is to create a CORE APP and render router of these apps inside the CORE APP based on the user selection using the concepts of Micro Frontend and Module Federation.

I am stuck on the Authentication part, i created a new client in Keycloak for the CORE APP. The probelm here is

- How can i get the token of each apps inside my core app so that i can use appropriate tokens as per the user selection in the axios.

if this is not a good practise please help me to make this better

Comment: What I infer from your question is that you have three different apps (I unsderstand that they're three different frontend projects), each with its related Keycloak client. You're trying to merge them in a core app. So what I would do is to use a single KC client for every of them and use roles to limit user authorizations.

Comment: @aritz Yes i also thought the same then i stumble upon this comment by one of the keycloak member https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/single-client-configuration-for-multiple-applications/2053/2 They are saying there are many risks involved and its not recommended. Since i am not  a master in KC i can't figure out the security risks

Comment: There is one more point here , Apart from the Micro Fronend container these apps have a standalone existance as itself , if i want to move to a single client approcah there will be a handful of changes in the frontend and backend as well , So my end goal is to make least minimum changes in the existing apps and make most of the changes in CORE APP